# El mismo programa pero con el ciclo While

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
main ()
{
    float sueldo,nomina,suma;
    int i;
    
    std::string empresa;
    
    std::cout<<"Introduce el nombre de la empresa:"<<"\n";
    std::getline(std::cin,empresa);
    
    for (i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Introduce el sueldo del trabajador"<<i<<":"<<"\n";
        std::cin>>sueldo;
        suma=suma+sueldo;
    }
    nomina=suma;
    std::cout<<"La empresa "<<empresa<<" debe pagar una nomina de: "<<suma;
    
    return 0;
}
```

No me doy una idea de como poder pasar este mismo programa haciendo uso del ciclo While,alguien me podría ayudar, el problema dice que se ingresen 12 sueldos y que al final se imprima la nomina a pagar por dicha empresa que anteriormente ya se pidió el nombre también.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estos códigos son equivalentes:

```
// Con for
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    std::cout << i;
}

// Con while
int i = 0;
while (i < 10){
    std::cout << i;
    i++;
}
```

Creo que con este ejemplo deberías ser capaz de entender la sutil diferencia entre ambos y reemplazar el for de tu código por un while.

La ventaja del for es poder escribir de forma más compacta el mismo código.

---

Si no te resulta evidente, te explico cómo se usa/funciona de cada uno.

Todo ciclo tiene el propósito de repetir el código en su cuerpo siempre que una condición se cumpla. El cuerpo en todos los casos se encuentra entre llaves.

En el caso del while, entre paréntesis indicas la condición.

En el caso del for, entre paréntesis van:

- Una instrucción que se ejecuta una única vez antes que nada.
- La condición, que se evalúa antes de cada repetición.
- Una instrucción que se ejecuta al final de cada repetición.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu explicación y la gran ayuda que me acabas de brindar amigo, ya establecí el código en el orden correspondiente y compila con facilidad